# XSLT grouping by sibling node value

Tags: xslt, key, grouping, muenchian-grouping

In the following sample XML subsides should be grouped to "Number"-node value. I already tried grouping the Muenchian method but couldn't get it done yet. The XSLT must be in 1.0. For every Number-node a box should be created and each value should be grouped to it. Problems is also possible multiple values in node, these should be shown separately. Thank you for any assistance you give me in this!

```
<ROOT>
<PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>002</Number>
      <Registration>27754</Registration>
      <Country>Finland</Country>
    <DATA>
  <PROC>

<PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>003</Number>
      <Registration>42852</Registration>
      <Country>Sweden</Country>
    <DATA>
  <PROC>

 <PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>003</Number>
      <Registration>H/11/019|H/11/020|H/11/021</Registration>
      <Country>Slovenia</Country>
    <DATA>
  <PROC>

<PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>002</Number>
      <Registration>19481</Registration>
      <Country>Denmark</Country>
    <DATA>
  <PROC>
<PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>004</Number>
      <Registration>09-23</Registration>
      <Country>Norway</Country>
    <DATA>
  <PROC>
</ROOT>
```

The above code should be shown as followed:

```
<main>
 <rbox>
  <vNumber>002</vNumber>
 <bbox>
  <State>Finland</State>
    <gbox>
      <Registrations>
        <Registration>27754</Registration>
      </Registrations>
    </gbox>
</bbox>
<bbox>
  <State>Denmark</State>
    <gbox>
      <Registrations>
        <Registration>19481</Registration>
      </Registrations>
    </gbox>
</bbox>
</rbox>

<rbox>
  <vNumber>003</vNumber>
 <bbox>
  <State>Slovenia</State>
    <gbox>
      <Registrations>
        <Registration>H/11/019</Registration>
      </Registrations>
      <Registrations>
        <Registration>H/11/020</Registration>
      </Registrations>
      <Registrations>
        <Registration>H/11/021</Registration>
      </Registrations>
    </gbox>
</bbox>
<bbox>
  <State>Sweden</State>
    <gbox>
      <Registrations>
        <Registration>42852</Registration>
      </Registrations>
    </gbox>
</bbox>
</rbox>
...
</main>
```

---

thank your for your fast response. Here is my code so far. I couldn't manage to get the Country and Registration Data to sort to the number record without creating multiple values. I also tried concate values in the key "use" but this also doesn't work.

```
<xsl:key name="country" match="ROOT/PROC/DATA" use="Country"/>
<xsl:key name="registration" match="ROOT/PROC/DATA" use="Registration"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">           
   <main> 
      <xsl:for-each select="//Number[not(.=preceding::*)]">
         <rbox>
                <xsl:element name="vNumber">
                    <vNumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></vNumber>                 
                    <xsl:for-each select="//DATA[generate-id() = generate-id(key('country', Country)[1])]">
                        <bbox>
                            <State><xsl:value-of select="Country"/></State>
                            <gbox>
                                <xsl:for-each select="//DATA[generate-id() = generate-id(key('registration', Registration)[1])]">
                                        <Registrations>
                                            <Registration><xsl:value-of select="Registration"/></Registration>
                                        </Registrations>    
                                </xsl:for-each>
                             </gbox>                 
                        </bbox>
                    </xsl:for-each>     
                </xsl:element> 
         </rbox> 
      </xsl:for-each>            
</main> 
</xsl:template>
```

**** EDIT: Complete stylesheet after help from  michael.hor257k regarding grouping problem ---> Concerned products

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"
xmlns:maa="http://www.oma.trp/maa/"
xmlns:rdm="http://www.oma.trp/dictionary/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
<xsl:param name="ns-prefix" select="'xfa'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-namespace" select="'http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-prefix1" select="'maa'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-namespace1" select="'http://www.oma.trp/maa/'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-prefix2" select="'rdm'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-namespace2" select="'http://www.oma.trp/dictionary/'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-prefix3" select="'xsi'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-namespace3" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-prefix4" select="'schemaLocation'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-namespace4" select="'http://www.oma.trp/maa/variations.xsd'"/>
<xsl:param name="ns-schema" select="'http://www.oma.trp/maa/variations.xsd'"/>
<xsl:variable name="vRdm" select="document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='rdm']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vXsi" select="document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='xsi']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSchemaLocation" select="document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='schemaLocation']"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix}:data" namespace="{$ns-namespace}">
    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:eu_application_form" namespace="{$ns-namespace1}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$vRdm"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$vXsi"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$vSchemaLocation"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">
            <xsl:value-of select="$ns-schema" />
        </xsl:attribute>

<xsl:template match="/">    
            <maa:variations-form>


            <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:applicationInformation">

                    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:human">1</xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:veterinary">0</xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:nationalAuthInMRP">1</xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:euAuthorisation">0</xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:nationalAuthorisation">0</xsl:element>

                    <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:procedureNumbers">
                        <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:procedureNumber"></xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>

                    <!--RMS country Loop start -->

                                            <xsl:template match="/">
                        <xsl:element name="{$ns-prefix1}:referenceMemberState">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="ROOT/PROC/DATA/Procedure_Number[contains(text(),'DK')]">
                                    <xsl:text>Denmark</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="ROOT/PROC/DATA/Procedure_Number[contains(text(),'SI')]">
                                    <xsl:text>Slovenia</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:template>

                    <!--RMS country Loop end -->

                                            <!--CMS country Loop start -->  


                                            <xsl:template match="/">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="//Country_Name[not(.=preceding::*)]">
                                                    <maa:concernedMemberStates>
                                                    <maa:concernedMemberState><xsl:value-of select="."/></maa:concernedMemberState>
                                                    </maa:concernedMemberStates>   
                                                    </xsl:for-each>            
                                            </xsl:template>


                    <!--CMS country Loop end -->


                    <!--CONCERNED PRODUCTS -->      
        </xsl:element>
                     <xsl:template match="/">       
                    <main>

                    <products>
                    <maa:formAndStrengthFlag>0</maa:formAndStrengthFlag>

                    <maa:footnote/>

                    <!--CONCERNED PRODUCTS -->  

                   <xsl:key name="strength" match="ROOT/PROC/DATA" use="Speciality_Number"/>


                        <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/PROC/DATA[generate-id() = generate-id(key('strength', Speciality_Number)[1])]">
                            <redbox>
                                <variationNumber><xsl:value-of select="Speciality_Number"/></variationNumber>

            <!-- for each member of the current group  -->
                                    <xsl:for-each select="key('strength', Speciality_Number)">
                                        <blueBox>
                                            <memberState><xsl:value-of select="Country_Name"/></memberState>
                                                <greenBox>
                                                    <maNumbers>
                                                        <maNumber><xsl:value-of select="Registration_Number"/></maNumber>                  
                                                    </maNumbers>
                                                </greenBox>
                                        </blueBox>
                                    </xsl:for-each>    
                            </redbox> 
                        </xsl:for-each>     




                    </products> 

                    </main>
                     </xsl:template>       

            </maa:variations-form>  
        </xsl:template> 


            </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="FSTEMPLATE_">/Applications/eAFForms/1.20/Forms/Variation/Form/variation.xdp
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="FSFORMQUERY_">/Applications/eAFForms/1.20/Forms/Variation/Form/variation.xdp
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="FSTRANSFORMATIONID_">PDFForm</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="FSTARGETURL_"/>
            <xsl:element name="FSAWR_"/>
            <xsl:element name="FSWR_"/>
            <xsl:element name="FSCRURI_">repository://</xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="FSBASEURL_"/>        
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group the `DATA` elements by `Number`, you need to make your key match `DATA` and use `Number`.

Try the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="DATA" use="Number"/>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">           
    <main>
        <!-- create a group for each distinct Number -->
        <xsl:for-each select="PROC/DATA[generate-id() = generate-id(key('grp', Number)[1])]">
            <rbox>
                <vNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
                </vNumber>
                <!-- for each member of the current group  -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('grp', Number)">
                    <bbox>
                        <State>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Country"/>
                        </State>
                        <gbox>
                            <Registrations>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="Registration"/>
                            </Registrations>
                        </gbox>
                    </bbox>
                 </xsl:for-each>    
             </rbox> 
        </xsl:for-each>   
    </main> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Your input is not well-formed XML, but when the above stylesheet is applied to the following input:

**XML**

```
<ROOT>
  <PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>002</Number>
      <Registration>27754</Registration>
      <Country>Finland</Country>
    </DATA>
  </PROC>
  <PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>003</Number>
      <Registration>42852</Registration>
      <Country>Sweden</Country>
    </DATA>
  </PROC>
  <PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>003</Number>
      <Registration>H/11/019|H/11/020|H/11/021</Registration>
      <Country>Slovenia</Country>
    </DATA>
  </PROC>
  <PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>002</Number>
      <Registration>19481</Registration>
      <Country>Denmark</Country>
    </DATA>
  </PROC>
  <PROC>
    <DATA>
      <Number>004</Number>
      <Registration>09-23</Registration>
      <Country>Norway</Country>
    </DATA>
  </PROC>
</ROOT>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
   <rbox>
      <vNumber>002</vNumber>
      <bbox>
         <State>Finland</State>
         <gbox>
            <Registrations>
               <Registration>27754</Registration>
            </Registrations>
         </gbox>
      </bbox>
      <bbox>
         <State>Denmark</State>
         <gbox>
            <Registrations>
               <Registration>19481</Registration>
            </Registrations>
         </gbox>
      </bbox>
   </rbox>
   <rbox>
      <vNumber>003</vNumber>
      <bbox>
         <State>Sweden</State>
         <gbox>
            <Registrations>
               <Registration>42852</Registration>
            </Registrations>
         </gbox>
      </bbox>
      <bbox>
         <State>Slovenia</State>
         <gbox>
            <Registrations>
               <Registration>H/11/019|H/11/020|H/11/021</Registration>
            </Registrations>
         </gbox>
      </bbox>
   </rbox>
   <rbox>
      <vNumber>004</vNumber>
      <bbox>
         <State>Norway</State>
         <gbox>
            <Registrations>
               <Registration>09-23</Registration>
            </Registrations>
         </gbox>
      </bbox>
   </rbox>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, this worked! However I'm facing a new problem now, this part above is nested inside a template match="/" and this part is simply ignored during the transformation. Can I place the complete stylesheet below or should I open a new question?

Comment: Why would you need to nest this inside another template? The above **is**  a complete stylesheet; what else are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited my first answer with my so far complete stylesheet,  inside nested is your solved problem regarding the grouping of the concerned products. Problem is now I think is that there is now a conflict  for the template rules, ignoring "Concerned product" loop (your solution).

Comment: Your stylesheet makes no sense considering the given input and the expected output. I suggest you post a new question.